# How can I know the dependency packages for an installed package?

Tags: apt, dpkg, aptitude

Let's say I installed `foo`. The `foo` package depends on `bar`, so `bar` was installed to satisfy `foo`'s dependency.

How can I get Ubuntu/APT/dpkg to tell me that `bar` is installed because `foo` is installed?

I know aptitude has a way to do this. But I can't for the life of me get it to switch the bottom pane to the "why installed" tab. How to do that would be a potential answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the command line you can run

```
aptitude why bar
```

This seems to do whatever it takes to provide an answer, meaning it will never tell you "explicitly installed" and will instead find a recommends or suggests that the package fulfills.